# Issue with integer subproblem in Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I am dealing with an integer model, and I'm using Dantzig-Wolfe (DW) algorithm that I have developed in Matlab to decompose the model into a master and sub-problems. I put the integer constraints in the sub-problems. The algorithm works fine; however, for some integer models I end up with a solution that needs to be rounded to nearest integers. I'm wondering: 1)am I using DW in the right context? I mean can DW be used to solve integer problems? does the model have to be continuous LP? Because an integer model in not convex. Doesn't DW require convexity? 2)How can I avoid rounding the solution? What improvement do I need to apply to the algorithm?
In the following I have elaborated the issue.

Assume the structure of the model under study is as below:
$$Min\ c_1^Tx_1+c_2^Tx_2+...+c_i^Tx_i+...+c_n^Tx_n$$
$$s.t. A_1x_1+A_2x_2+...+A_ix_i+...+A_nx_n=b$$
$$B_1x_1=r_1$$
$$B_2x_2=r_2$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$B_nx_n=r_n$$
$$x_i \in \{0,1\}^{m_i}$$
We know that the above model has the following restricted master problem (RMP):
$$RMP: Min\ \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\sum_{i \in J} \lambda_{ij}(c_i^Tx_{ij}) $$
$$s.t. \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\sum_{i \in J} \lambda_{ij}(A_ix_{ij})=b \ \ \ \ \ (\pi_{0j})$$
$$\sum_{i \in J}^{n}\lambda_{ij}=1 \ \ \ \ \ (\pi_{ij})$$
$$\lambda_{ij} \in \mathbb{R_+}$$

The subproblems are:
$$SP_i: Min \ (c_i-\pi_{0j}^TA_i)^T-\pi_{ij}$$
$$s.t. B_ix_{ij}=r_i \ , x_{ij} \in \{0,1\}^{m_i}$$

$\pi_{0j}$ and $\pi_{ij}$ are the dual variables. We know at the end, which is when $0\leq (c_i-\pi_{0j}^TA_i)^T-\pi_{ij}$ for any $i$ and $j$, the final optimal solution for subproblem $i$ is computed as $x_i^*$=$\sum_{j \in J} \lambda_{ij}x_{ij}$. This is where I get a non-integer value for $x^*$. The model is integer. All the $x_{ij}$ I get from the subproblems are integer. However, the result of the sum $\sum_{j \in J} \lambda_{ij}x_{ij}$ sometimes lead to a non-integer value, which I have to round up. The rounded $x^*$ is always the correct answer.
Please let me know how I can avoid the rounding at the end of optimization. Why the sum leads to non-integer solutions?

Comment: check Branch&Price (when dantzig-wolfe is coupled to branch and bound).

Comment: What is being rounded, the solution to the MILP subproblem or the solution to the master problem?

Comment: I just edited the question and added further explanation.

Comment: There are situations where doing column generation (I'm not sure whether it is correct to call it D-W) with integer subproblems and a continuous master problem makes sense. For instance, the subproblem might generate feasible routes through a network and the master problem might allocate (continuous) flow across the routes. As Rob notes in his answer, this does not extend to the case where the master problem also contains integer variables. That is where branch-and-price comes in.

Answer (score 2):

Even if $x$ takes integer values, there is no guarantee that $\sum_j \lambda_{ij} x_{ij}$ does, and there is also no guarantee that rounding this convex combination gives you an optimal or even an integer feasible solution.  When there are no more improving columns from the subproblems, you have solved the root node of the master problem.  If the resulting convex combination solution is not integer, you then need to branch, and the full algorithm of column generation within branch-and-bound is called *branch-and-price*, which is what @Kuifje mentioned in a comment.

Comment: I have one more question about DW decomposition algorithm. The convergence of the algorithm I have developed on my own depends on what initial $x_{ij}$ (which are the corner points of the subproblems) I choose. Looks like there are proper corner points that I must start with. Is that normal? Currently, I keep rerunning the algorithm with random initial corner points until it converges. Deepening on the start point, the model either becomes initially infeasible or leads to the correct answer.

Comment: For DW (and column generation in general), a good set of initial columns can reduce the number of iterations needed.  But it is not required for correctness.  You can use a two-phase approach (like in the two-phase simplex method for LP) where phase 1 finds a feasible LP solution and phase 2 improves it to an optimal LP solution.  For phase 1, you need artificial variables that take a value of $0$ when you have a feasible solution.

Comment: I need to clarify that it is guaranteed that the solutions I receive from the subproblems are always integer because of the constraint $x_{ij} \in \{0,1\}^{m_i}$. It is only the sum $\sum_j \lambda_{ij} x_{ij}$ at the very last stage that leads to a non-integer solution. Could I resolve the RMP at the last stage with an additional constraint on $\lambda$ (i.e., $\lambda \in \{0,1\}$)? Because that seems to be the only way to make $x_i^*$ be integer.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the subproblem solutions are integer feasible. A common *heuristic* called “price-and-branch” is to solve the final RMP with integer restrictions imposed on $\lambda$, but it is not guaranteed to return a solution that is optimal (or even feasible) to the original problem.

Comment: That's good that the "branch-and-price" has to be applied only on the last iteration. I was wondering if I would have to apply it at every single iteration of the RMP.